# FontIconPicker doesn't show icons correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, font-awesome, picker

I'm using FontIconPicker with fontawesome but the picker doesn't show the icons, only shows a square with the code (for example: F2B9 for fa-address-book)

What I'm using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/@fonticonpicker/fonticonpicker/dist/css/base/jquery.fonticonpicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/@fonticonpicker/fonticonpicker/dist/css/themes/grey-theme/jquery.fonticonpicker.grey.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@fonticonpicker/fonticonpicker/dist/js/jquery.fonticonpicker.min.js"></script>
```

The picker:

```
//html
<div id="iconsecc"></div>
//js
var params = {
     theme: 'fip-bootstrap',
     source: iconscat
};
$('#iconsecc').fontIconPicker(params);
```

The icon source:

```
var iconscat = {
    "Accessibility": [
        "fas fa-american-sign-language-interpreting",
        "fas fa-assistive-listening-systems",
        "fas fa-audio-description",
        "fas fa-blind",
        "fas fa-braille",
        "fas fa-closed-captioning",
        "fas fa-deaf",
        "fas fa-low-vision",
        "fas fa-phone-volume",
        "fas fa-question-circle",
        "fas fa-sign-language",
        "fas fa-tty",
        "fas fa-universal-access",
        "fas fa-wheelchair"
    ],
    "Arrows": [
        "fas fa-angle-double-down",
        "fas fa-angle-double-left",
        "fas fa-angle-double-right",
        "fas fa-angle-double-up",
        "fas fa-angle-down",
        "fas fa-angle-left",
        "fas fa-angle-right",
        "fas fa-angle-up",
        "fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down",
        "fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left",
        "fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right",
        "fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up",
        "fas fa-arrow-circle-down",
        "fas fa-arrow-circle-left",
        "fas fa-arrow-circle-right",
        "fas fa-arrow-circle-up",
        "fas fa-arrow-down",
        "fas fa-arrow-left",
        "fas fa-arrow-right",
        "fas fa-arrow-up",
        "fas fa-arrows-alt",
        "fas fa-arrows-alt-h",
        "fas fa-arrows-alt-v",
        "fas fa-caret-down",
        "fas fa-caret-left",
        "fas fa-caret-right",
        "fas fa-caret-square-down",
        "fas fa-caret-square-left",
        "fas fa-caret-square-right",
        "fas fa-caret-square-up",
        "fas fa-caret-up",
        "fas fa-cart-arrow-down",
        "fas fa-chart-line",
        "fas fa-chevron-circle-down",
        "fas fa-chevron-circle-left",
        "fas fa-chevron-circle-right",
        "fas fa-chevron-circle-up",
        "fas fa-chevron-down",
        "fas fa-chevron-left",
        "fas fa-chevron-right",
        "fas fa-chevron-up",
        "fas fa-cloud-download-alt",
        "fas fa-cloud-upload-alt",
        "fas fa-download",
        "fas fa-exchange-alt",
        "fas fa-expand-arrows-alt",
        "fas fa-external-link-alt",
        "fas fa-external-link-square-alt",
        "fas fa-hand-point-down",
        "fas fa-hand-point-left",
        "fas fa-hand-point-right",
        "fas fa-hand-point-up",
        "fas fa-hand-pointer",
        "fas fa-history",
        "fas fa-level-down-alt",
        "fas fa-level-up-alt",
        "fas fa-location-arrow",
        "fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down",
        "fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left",
        "fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right",
        "fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up",
        "fas fa-mouse-pointer",
        "fas fa-play",
        "fas fa-random",
        "fas fa-recycle",
        "fas fa-redo",
        "fas fa-redo-alt",
        "fas fa-reply",
        "fas fa-reply-all",
        "fas fa-retweet",
        "fas fa-share",
        "fas fa-share-square",
        "fas fa-sign-in-alt",
        "fas fa-sign-out-alt",
        "fas fa-sort",
        "fas fa-sort-alpha-down",
        "fas fa-sort-alpha-up",
        "fas fa-sort-amount-down",
        "fas fa-sort-amount-up",
        "fas fa-sort-down",
        "fas fa-sort-numeric-down",
        "fas fa-sort-numeric-up",
        "fas fa-sort-up",
        "fas fa-sync",
        "fas fa-sync-alt",
        "fas fa-text-height",
        "fas fa-text-width",
        "fas fa-undo",
        "fas fa-undo-alt",
        "fas fa-upload"
    ],
    "Audio & Video": [
        "fas fa-audio-description",
        "fas fa-backward",
        "fas fa-circle",
        "fas fa-closed-captioning",
        "fas fa-compress",
        "fas fa-eject",
        "fas fa-expand",
        "fas fa-expand-arrows-alt",
        "fas fa-fast-backward",
        "fas fa-fast-forward",
        "fas fa-file-audio",
        "fas fa-file-video",
        "fas fa-film",
        "fas fa-forward",
        "fas fa-headphones",
        "fas fa-microphone",
        "fas fa-microphone-slash",
        "fas fa-music",
        "fas fa-pause",
        "fas fa-pause-circle",
        "fas fa-phone-volume",
        "fas fa-play",
        "fas fa-play-circle",
        "fas fa-podcast",
        "fas fa-random",
        "fas fa-redo",
        "fas fa-redo-alt",
        "fas fa-rss",
        "fas fa-rss-square",
        "fas fa-step-backward",
        "fas fa-step-forward",
        "fas fa-stop",
        "fas fa-stop-circle",
        "fas fa-sync",
        "fas fa-sync-alt",
        "fas fa-undo",
        "fas fa-undo-alt",
        "fas fa-video",
        "fas fa-volume-down",
        "fas fa-volume-off",
        "fas fa-volume-up"
    ],
    "Business": [
        "fas fa-address-book",
        "fas fa-address-card",
        "fas fa-archive",
        "fas fa-balance-scale",
        "fas fa-birthday-cake",
        "fas fa-book",
        "fas fa-briefcase",
        "fas fa-building",
        "fas fa-bullhorn",
        "fas fa-bullseye",
        "fas fa-calculator",
        "fas fa-calendar",
        "fas fa-calendar-alt",
        "fas fa-certificate",
        "fas fa-chart-area",
        "fas fa-chart-bar",
        "fas fa-chart-line",
        "fas fa-chart-pie",
        "fas fa-clipboard",
        "fas fa-coffee",
        "fas fa-columns",
        "fas fa-compass",
        "fas fa-copy",
        "fas fa-copyright",
        "fas fa-cut",
        "fas fa-edit",
        "fas fa-envelope",
        "fas fa-envelope-open",
        "fas fa-envelope-square",
        "fas fa-eraser",
        "fas fa-fax",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-folder",
        "fas fa-folder-open",
        "fas fa-globe",
        "fas fa-industry",
        "fas fa-paperclip",
        "fas fa-paste",
        "fas fa-pen-square",
        "fas fa-pencil-alt",
        "fas fa-percent",
        "fas fa-phone",
        "fas fa-phone-square",
        "fas fa-phone-volume",
        "fas fa-registered",
        "fas fa-save",
        "fas fa-sitemap",
        "fas fa-sticky-note",
        "fas fa-suitcase",
        "fas fa-table",
        "fas fa-tag",
        "fas fa-tags",
        "fas fa-tasks",
        "fas fa-thumbtack",
        "fas fa-trademark"
    ],
    "Chess": [
        "fas fa-chess",
        "fas fa-chess-bishop",
        "fas fa-chess-board",
        "fas fa-chess-king",
        "fas fa-chess-knight",
        "fas fa-chess-pawn",
        "fas fa-chess-queen",
        "fas fa-chess-rook",
        "fas fa-square-full"
    ],
    "Code": [
        "fas fa-archive",
        "fas fa-barcode",
        "fas fa-bath",
        "fas fa-bug",
        "fas fa-code",
        "fas fa-code-branch",
        "fas fa-coffee",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-file-code",
        "fas fa-filter",
        "fas fa-fire-extinguisher",
        "fas fa-folder",
        "fas fa-folder-open",
        "fas fa-keyboard",
        "fas fa-microchip",
        "fas fa-qrcode",
        "fas fa-shield-alt",
        "fas fa-sitemap",
        "fas fa-terminal",
        "fas fa-user-secret",
        "fas fa-window-close",
        "fas fa-window-maximize",
        "fas fa-window-minimize",
        "fas fa-window-restore"
    ],
    "Communication": [
        "fas fa-address-book",
        "fas fa-address-card",
        "fas fa-american-sign-language-interpreting",
        "fas fa-assistive-listening-systems",
        "fas fa-at",
        "fas fa-bell",
        "fas fa-bell-slash",
        "fas fa-bullhorn",
        "fas fa-comment",
        "fas fa-comment-alt",
        "fas fa-comments",
        "fas fa-envelope",
        "fas fa-envelope-open",
        "fas fa-envelope-square",
        "fas fa-fax",
        "fas fa-inbox",
        "fas fa-language",
        "fas fa-microphone",
        "fas fa-microphone-slash",
        "fas fa-mobile",
        "fas fa-mobile-alt",
        "fas fa-paper-plane",
        "fas fa-phone",
        "fas fa-phone-square",
        "fas fa-phone-volume",
        "fas fa-rss",
        "fas fa-rss-square",
        "fas fa-tty",
        "fas fa-wifi"
    ],
    "Computers": [
        "fas fa-desktop",
        "fas fa-download",
        "fas fa-hdd",
        "fas fa-headphones",
        "fas fa-keyboard",
        "fas fa-laptop",
        "fas fa-microchip",
        "fas fa-mobile",
        "fas fa-mobile-alt",
        "fas fa-plug",
        "fas fa-power-off",
        "fas fa-print",
        "fas fa-save",
        "fas fa-server",
        "fas fa-tablet",
        "fas fa-tablet-alt",
        "fas fa-tv",
        "fas fa-upload"
    ],
    "Currency": [
        "fas fa-dollar-sign",
        "fas fa-euro-sign",
        "fas fa-lira-sign",
        "fas fa-money-bill-alt",
        "fas fa-pound-sign",
        "fas fa-ruble-sign",
        "fas fa-rupee-sign",
        "fas fa-shekel-sign",
        "fas fa-won-sign",
        "fas fa-yen-sign"
    ],
    "Date & Time": [
        "fas fa-bell",
        "fas fa-bell-slash",
        "fas fa-calendar",
        "fas fa-calendar-alt",
        "fas fa-calendar-check",
        "fas fa-calendar-minus",
        "fas fa-calendar-plus",
        "fas fa-calendar-times",
        "fas fa-clock",
        "fas fa-hourglass",
        "fas fa-hourglass-end",
        "fas fa-hourglass-half",
        "fas fa-hourglass-start",
        "fas fa-stopwatch"
    ],
    "Design": [
        "fas fa-adjust",
        "fas fa-clone",
        "fas fa-copy",
        "fas fa-crop",
        "fas fa-crosshairs",
        "fas fa-cut",
        "fas fa-edit",
        "fas fa-eraser",
        "fas fa-eye",
        "fas fa-eye-dropper",
        "fas fa-eye-slash",
        "fas fa-object-group",
        "fas fa-object-ungroup",
        "fas fa-paint-brush",
        "fas fa-paste",
        "fas fa-pencil-alt",
        "fas fa-save",
        "fas fa-tint"
    ],
    "Editors": [
        "fas fa-align-center",
        "fas fa-align-justify",
        "fas fa-align-left",
        "fas fa-align-right",
        "fas fa-bold",
        "fas fa-clipboard",
        "fas fa-clone",
        "fas fa-columns",
        "fas fa-copy",
        "fas fa-cut",
        "fas fa-edit",
        "fas fa-eraser",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-font",
        "fas fa-heading",
        "fas fa-i-cursor",
        "fas fa-indent",
        "fas fa-italic",
        "fas fa-link",
        "fas fa-list",
        "fas fa-list-alt",
        "fas fa-list-ol",
        "fas fa-list-ul",
        "fas fa-outdent",
        "fas fa-paper-plane",
        "fas fa-paperclip",
        "fas fa-paragraph",
        "fas fa-paste",
        "fas fa-pencil-alt",
        "fas fa-print",
        "fas fa-quote-left",
        "fas fa-quote-right",
        "fas fa-redo",
        "fas fa-redo-alt",
        "fas fa-reply",
        "fas fa-reply-all",
        "fas fa-share",
        "fas fa-strikethrough",
        "fas fa-subscript",
        "fas fa-superscript",
        "fas fa-sync",
        "fas fa-sync-alt",
        "fas fa-table",
        "fas fa-tasks",
        "fas fa-text-height",
        "fas fa-text-width",
        "fas fa-th",
        "fas fa-th-large",
        "fas fa-th-list",
        "fas fa-trash",
        "fas fa-trash-alt",
        "fas fa-underline",
        "fas fa-undo",
        "fas fa-undo-alt",
        "fas fa-unlink"
    ],
    "Files": [
        "fas fa-archive",
        "fas fa-clone",
        "fas fa-copy",
        "fas fa-cut",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-file-archive",
        "fas fa-file-audio",
        "fas fa-file-code",
        "fas fa-file-excel",
        "fas fa-file-image",
        "fas fa-file-pdf",
        "fas fa-file-powerpoint",
        "fas fa-file-video",
        "fas fa-file-word",
        "fas fa-folder",
        "fas fa-folder-open",
        "fas fa-paste",
        "fas fa-save",
        "fas fa-sticky-note"
    ],
    "Genders": [
        "fas fa-genderless",
        "fas fa-mars",
        "fas fa-mars-double",
        "fas fa-mars-stroke",
        "fas fa-mars-stroke-h",
        "fas fa-mars-stroke-v",
        "fas fa-mercury",
        "fas fa-neuter",
        "fas fa-transgender",
        "fas fa-transgender-alt",
        "fas fa-venus",
        "fas fa-venus-double",
        "fas fa-venus-mars"
    ],
    "Hands": [
        "fas fa-hand-lizard",
        "fas fa-hand-paper",
        "fas fa-hand-peace",
        "fas fa-hand-point-down",
        "fas fa-hand-point-left",
        "fas fa-hand-point-right",
        "fas fa-hand-point-up",
        "fas fa-hand-pointer",
        "fas fa-hand-rock",
        "fas fa-hand-scissors",
        "fas fa-hand-spock",
        "fas fa-handshake",
        "fas fa-thumbs-down",
        "fas fa-thumbs-up"
    ],
    "Health": [
        "fas fa-ambulance",
        "fas fa-h-square",
        "fas fa-heart",
        "fas fa-heartbeat",
        "fas fa-hospital",
        "fas fa-medkit",
        "fas fa-plus-square",
        "fas fa-stethoscope",
        "fas fa-user-md",
        "fas fa-wheelchair"
    ],
    "Images": [
        "fas fa-adjust",
        "fas fa-bolt",
        "fas fa-camera",
        "fas fa-camera-retro",
        "fas fa-clone",
        "fas fa-compress",
        "fas fa-expand",
        "fas fa-eye",
        "fas fa-eye-dropper",
        "fas fa-eye-slash",
        "fas fa-file-image",
        "fas fa-film",
        "fas fa-id-badge",
        "fas fa-id-card",
        "fas fa-image",
        "fas fa-images",
        "fas fa-sliders-h",
        "fas fa-tint"
    ],
    "Interfaces": [
        "fas fa-ban",
        "fas fa-barcode",
        "fas fa-bars",
        "fas fa-beer",
        "fas fa-bell",
        "fas fa-bell-slash",
        "fas fa-bug",
        "fas fa-bullhorn",
        "fas fa-bullseye",
        "fas fa-calculator",
        "fas fa-calendar",
        "fas fa-calendar-alt",
        "fas fa-calendar-check",
        "fas fa-calendar-minus",
        "fas fa-calendar-plus",
        "fas fa-calendar-times",
        "fas fa-certificate",
        "fas fa-check",
        "fas fa-check-circle",
        "fas fa-check-square",
        "fas fa-circle",
        "fas fa-clipboard",
        "fas fa-clone",
        "fas fa-cloud",
        "fas fa-cloud-download-alt",
        "fas fa-cloud-upload-alt",
        "fas fa-coffee",
        "fas fa-cog",
        "fas fa-cogs",
        "fas fa-copy",
        "fas fa-cut",
        "fas fa-database",
        "fas fa-dot-circle",
        "fas fa-download",
        "fas fa-edit",
        "fas fa-ellipsis-h",
        "fas fa-ellipsis-v",
        "fas fa-envelope",
        "fas fa-envelope-open",
        "fas fa-eraser",
        "fas fa-exclamation",
        "fas fa-exclamation-circle",
        "fas fa-exclamation-triangle",
        "fas fa-external-link-alt",
        "fas fa-external-link-square-alt",
        "fas fa-eye",
        "fas fa-eye-slash",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-filter",
        "fas fa-flag",
        "fas fa-flag-checkered",
        "fas fa-folder",
        "fas fa-folder-open",
        "fas fa-frown",
        "fas fa-hashtag",
        "fas fa-heart",
        "fas fa-history",
        "fas fa-home",
        "fas fa-i-cursor",
        "fas fa-info",
        "fas fa-info-circle",
        "fas fa-language",
        "fas fa-magic",
        "fas fa-meh",
        "fas fa-microphone",
        "fas fa-microphone-slash",
        "fas fa-minus",
        "fas fa-minus-circle",
        "fas fa-minus-square",
        "fas fa-paste",
        "fas fa-pencil-alt",
        "fas fa-plus",
        "fas fa-plus-circle",
        "fas fa-plus-square",
        "fas fa-qrcode",
        "fas fa-question",
        "fas fa-question-circle"
    ],
    "Maps": [
        "fas fa-ambulance",
        "fas fa-anchor",
        "fas fa-balance-scale",
        "fas fa-bath",
        "fas fa-bed",
        "fas fa-beer",
        "fas fa-bell",
        "fas fa-bell-slash",
        "fas fa-bicycle",
        "fas fa-binoculars",
        "fas fa-birthday-cake",
        "fas fa-blind",
        "fas fa-bomb",
        "fas fa-book",
        "fas fa-bookmark",
        "fas fa-briefcase",
        "fas fa-building",
        "fas fa-car",
        "fas fa-coffee",
        "fas fa-crosshairs",
        "fas fa-dollar-sign",
        "fas fa-eye",
        "fas fa-eye-slash",
        "fas fa-fighter-jet",
        "fas fa-fire",
        "fas fa-fire-extinguisher",
        "fas fa-flag",
        "fas fa-flag-checkered",
        "fas fa-flask",
        "fas fa-gamepad",
        "fas fa-gavel",
        "fas fa-gift",
        "fas fa-glass-martini",
        "fas fa-globe",
        "fas fa-graduation-cap",
        "fas fa-h-square",
        "fas fa-heart",
        "fas fa-heartbeat",
        "fas fa-home",
        "fas fa-hospital",
        "fas fa-image",
        "fas fa-images",
        "fas fa-industry",
        "fas fa-info",
        "fas fa-info-circle",
        "fas fa-key",
        "fas fa-leaf",
        "fas fa-lemon",
        "fas fa-life-ring",
        "fas fa-lightbulb",
        "fas fa-location-arrow",
        "fas fa-low-vision",
        "fas fa-magnet",
        "fas fa-male",
        "fas fa-map",
        "fas fa-map-marker",
        "fas fa-map-marker-alt",
        "fas fa-map-pin",
        "fas fa-map-signs",
        "fas fa-medkit",
        "fas fa-money-bill-alt",
        "fas fa-motorcycle",
        "fas fa-music",
        "fas fa-newspaper",
        "fas fa-paw",
        "fas fa-phone",
        "fas fa-phone-square",
        "fas fa-phone-volume",
        "fas fa-plane",
        "fas fa-plug",
        "fas fa-plus",
        "fas fa-plus-square",
        "fas fa-print",
        "fas fa-recycle",
        "fas fa-road",
        "fas fa-rocket",
        "fas fa-search",
        "fas fa-search-minus",
        "fas fa-search-plus",
        "fas fa-ship",
        "fas fa-shopping-bag",
        "fas fa-shopping-basket",
        "fas fa-shopping-cart",
        "fas fa-shower",
        "fas fa-street-view",
        "fas fa-subway",
        "fas fa-suitcase",
        "fas fa-tag",
        "fas fa-tags",
        "fas fa-taxi",
        "fas fa-thumbtack"
    ],
    "Objects": [
        "fas fa-ambulance",
        "fas fa-anchor",
        "fas fa-archive",
        "fas fa-balance-scale",
        "fas fa-bath",
        "fas fa-bed",
        "fas fa-beer",
        "fas fa-bell",
        "fas fa-bicycle",
        "fas fa-binoculars",
        "fas fa-birthday-cake",
        "fas fa-bomb",
        "fas fa-book",
        "fas fa-bookmark",
        "fas fa-briefcase",
        "fas fa-bug",
        "fas fa-building",
        "fas fa-bullhorn",
        "fas fa-bullseye",
        "fas fa-bus",
        "fas fa-calculator",
        "fas fa-calendar",
        "fas fa-calendar-alt",
        "fas fa-camera",
        "fas fa-camera-retro",
        "fas fa-car",
        "fas fa-clipboard",
        "fas fa-cloud",
        "fas fa-coffee",
        "fas fa-cog",
        "fas fa-cogs",
        "fas fa-compass",
        "fas fa-copy",
        "fas fa-cube",
        "fas fa-cubes",
        "fas fa-cut",
        "fas fa-envelope",
        "fas fa-envelope-open",
        "fas fa-eraser",
        "fas fa-eye",
        "fas fa-eye-dropper",
        "fas fa-fax",
        "fas fa-fighter-jet",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-film",
        "fas fa-fire",
        "fas fa-fire-extinguisher",
        "fas fa-flag",
        "fas fa-flag-checkered",
        "fas fa-flask",
        "fas fa-futbol",
        "fas fa-gamepad",
        "fas fa-gavel",
        "fas fa-gem",
        "fas fa-gift",
        "fas fa-glass-martini",
        "fas fa-globe",
        "fas fa-graduation-cap",
        "fas fa-hdd",
        "fas fa-headphones",
        "fas fa-heart",
        "fas fa-home",
        "fas fa-hospital",
        "fas fa-hourglass",
        "fas fa-image",
        "fas fa-images",
        "fas fa-industry",
        "fas fa-key",
        "fas fa-keyboard",
        "fas fa-laptop",
        "fas fa-leaf",
        "fas fa-lemon",
        "fas fa-life-ring",
        "fas fa-lightbulb",
        "fas fa-lock",
        "fas fa-lock-open",
        "fas fa-magic",
        "fas fa-magnet",
        "fas fa-map",
        "fas fa-map-marker",
        "fas fa-map-marker-alt"
    ],
    "Payments & Shopping": [
        "fas fa-bell",
        "fas fa-bookmark",
        "fas fa-bullhorn",
        "fas fa-camera",
        "fas fa-camera-retro",
        "fas fa-cart-arrow-down",
        "fas fa-cart-plus",
        "fas fa-certificate",
        "fas fa-credit-card",
        "fas fa-gem",
        "fas fa-gift",
        "fas fa-handshake",
        "fas fa-heart",
        "fas fa-key",
        "fas fa-shopping-bag",
        "fas fa-shopping-basket",
        "fas fa-shopping-cart",
        "fas fa-star",
        "fas fa-tag",
        "fas fa-tags",
        "fas fa-thumbs-down",
        "fas fa-thumbs-up",
        "fas fa-trophy"
    ],
    "Shapes": [
        "fas fa-bookmark",
        "fas fa-calendar",
        "fas fa-certificate",
        "fas fa-circle",
        "fas fa-cloud",
        "fas fa-comment",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-folder",
        "fas fa-heart",
        "fas fa-map-marker",
        "fas fa-play",
        "fas fa-square",
        "fas fa-star"
    ],
    "Spinners": [
        "fas fa-asterisk",
        "fas fa-certificate",
        "fas fa-circle-notch",
        "fas fa-cog",
        "fas fa-compass",
        "fas fa-crosshairs",
        "fas fa-life-ring",
        "fas fa-snowflake",
        "fas fa-spinner",
        "fas fa-sun",
        "fas fa-sync"
    ],
    "Sports": [
        "fas fa-baseball-ball",
        "fas fa-basketball-ball",
        "fas fa-bowling-ball",
        "fas fa-football-ball",
        "fas fa-futbol",
        "fas fa-golf-ball",
        "fas fa-hockey-puck",
        "fas fa-quidditch",
        "fas fa-table-tennis",
        "fas fa-volleyball-ball"
    ],
    "Status": [
        "fas fa-ban",
        "fas fa-battery-empty",
        "fas fa-battery-full",
        "fas fa-battery-half",
        "fas fa-battery-quarter",
        "fas fa-battery-three-quarters",
        "fas fa-bell",
        "fas fa-bell-slash",
        "fas fa-calendar",
        "fas fa-calendar-alt",
        "fas fa-calendar-check",
        "fas fa-calendar-minus",
        "fas fa-calendar-plus",
        "fas fa-calendar-times",
        "fas fa-cart-arrow-down",
        "fas fa-cart-plus",
        "fas fa-exclamation",
        "fas fa-exclamation-circle",
        "fas fa-exclamation-triangle",
        "fas fa-eye",
        "fas fa-eye-slash",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-folder",
        "fas fa-folder-open",
        "fas fa-info",
        "fas fa-info-circle",
        "fas fa-lock",
        "fas fa-lock-open",
        "fas fa-minus",
        "fas fa-minus-circle",
        "fas fa-minus-square",
        "fas fa-plus",
        "fas fa-plus-circle",
        "fas fa-plus-square",
        "fas fa-question",
        "fas fa-question-circle",
        "fas fa-shield-alt",
        "fas fa-shopping-cart",
        "fas fa-sign-in-alt",
        "fas fa-sign-out-alt",
        "fas fa-thermometer-empty",
        "fas fa-thermometer-full",
        "fas fa-thermometer-half",
        "fas fa-thermometer-quarter",
        "fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters",
        "fas fa-thumbs-down",
        "fas fa-thumbs-up",
        "fas fa-toggle-off",
        "fas fa-toggle-on",
        "fas fa-unlock",
        "fas fa-unlock-alt"
    ],
    "Users & People": [
        "fas fa-address-book",
        "fas fa-address-card",
        "fas fa-bed",
        "fas fa-blind",
        "fas fa-child",
        "fas fa-female",
        "fas fa-frown",
        "fas fa-id-badge",
        "fas fa-id-card",
        "fas fa-male",
        "fas fa-meh",
        "fas fa-power-off",
        "fas fa-smile",
        "fas fa-street-view",
        "fas fa-user",
        "fas fa-user-circle",
        "fas fa-user-md",
        "fas fa-user-plus",
        "fas fa-user-secret",
        "fas fa-user-times",
        "fas fa-users",
        "fas fa-wheelchair"
    ],
    "Vehicles": [
        "fas fa-ambulance",
        "fas fa-bicycle",
        "fas fa-bus",
        "fas fa-car",
        "fas fa-fighter-jet",
        "fas fa-motorcycle",
        "fas fa-paper-plane",
        "fas fa-plane",
        "fas fa-rocket",
        "fas fa-ship",
        "fas fa-shopping-cart",
        "fas fa-space-shuttle",
        "fas fa-subway",
        "fas fa-taxi",
        "fas fa-train",
        "fas fa-truck",
        "fas fa-wheelchair"
    ],
    "Writing": [
        "fas fa-archive",
        "fas fa-book",
        "fas fa-bookmark",
        "fas fa-edit",
        "fas fa-envelope",
        "fas fa-envelope-open",
        "fas fa-eraser",
        "fas fa-file",
        "fas fa-file-alt",
        "fas fa-folder",
        "fas fa-folder-open",
        "fas fa-keyboard",
        "fas fa-newspaper",
        "fas fa-paper-plane",
        "fas fa-paperclip",
        "fas fa-paragraph",
        "fas fa-pen-square",
        "fas fa-pencil-alt",
        "fas fa-quote-left",
        "fas fa-quote-right",
        "fas fa-sticky-note",
        "fas fa-thumbtack"
    ]
};
```

The result:
[image]

I tried to change the source with this (array instead of object) for testing and the result was the same:

```
source: ['fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-users']
```

Comment: Are you setting the `className` of the element?

Comment: Move the fontawesome stylesheet `<link>` below the others: https://jsfiddle.net/3jkpoq01/